# Android 12 splash screen setKeepVisibleCondition

Tags: android, splash-screen

I'm trying to implement a splash screen using android 12 SplashScreen compat library. I want to fetch some data from API each time my app starts. So the splash screen should wait until the API calls finish. I found this  `splashScreen.setKeepVisibleCondition()` function in docs, but don't know how to implement `KeepScreenOnCondition`. How can I make my splash screen to wait? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the solution.

```
private var isLoading = true

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
    splashScreen.setKeepVisibleCondition { isLoading }
}

private fun doApiCalls(){
    ...
    isLoading = false
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me.

Comment: @hushed_voice Maybe `isLoading` needs to be annotated with `@Volatile`.

Comment: What is that Kotlen? It seems the method setKeepVisibleCondition does not receive a boolean. Rather it receives a instance of the KeepVisibleCondition interface which should have an instance of the shouldKeepOnScreen() method.

Answer (score 0):

@sujith's answer did not work for me for some reason.

I added a method in my viewModel like this:

```
fun isDataReady(): Boolean {
    return isDataReady.value?:false
}
```

and used

```
splashScreen.setKeepVisibleCondition {
    !viewModel.isDataReady()
}
```

This worked for me.
May be someone can explain to me why sujiths answer was not working for me( it was hiding the splash screen after some time). Because I know both of us are essentially doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @hushed_voice's answer, *setKeepVisibleCondition()* will keep the Splash Screen on as long as it's returning true. Once it equates to false, the Splash will finish and your app will proceed forward.

Here is a short function I wrote up to handle my Splash Screen logic in my Main Activity:

```
private fun splashScreen() {
    val splash = installSplashScreen()
    splash.setKeepVisibleCondition{
        viewModel.initialize()
    }
}
```

Inside my ViewModel, the *initialize()* function does some asynchronous work, after which it returns false.

```
fun initialize(): Boolean {
    return !isDataReady
}
```

Till then my Splash Screen is present, after which it goes away. You should be able to throw in your API calls in this block and use a Reactive library to wait for them to complete before returning false. This is working perfectly for me.